# Google Static Maps API в exe-приложении

Tags: google-maps-api

Есть ли в настоящее время возможность использования Google Static Maps API в exe-приложении (не из браузера)?
Используя стандартный бесплатный план доступа?
Какое-то время назад назад на сайте Google писалось, что для этого необходим доступ уровня Static Maps API for WORK, и бесплатно можно работать только из браузера. Сейчас это требование, кажется, снято (я его, по крайней мере, больше не вижу).

Пытаюсь послать запрос

`https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?    center=55.0,65.0&size=400x400&format=png&maptype=roadmap`

Получаю ответ **HTTP 1.1/403 Forbidden**

Отправляю

```
{то же самое}&key=API_KEY
```

где *API_KEY* - ключ, полученный на сайте Google (Browser key) - получаю ответ **HTTP 1.1/403 Forbidden**

Отправляю

`{то же самое}&key=API_KEY&signature=SIGNATURE`

где *SIGNATURE* - Base64-подпись, сформированная через секрет, полученный опять же на сайте Google - получаю все тот же HTTP 1.1/403 Forbidden

В чем моя проблема - в кривых запросах, или в недостатке прав бесплатного доступа? Квоты не превышались - они не были даже тронуты.

---

+

Изменил ключ с Browser key на Server key - проблема осталась

Comment: в параметре size у вас кривой символ ×, замените его на символ x, возможно причина в этом

Comment: Была опечатка, исправил. Нет, не помогло

Comment: Попробуйте также отправить запрос на http

Comment: @Dmitry Пробовал)